# Android | Parse.com - Importing Parse-UI

Tags: android, parse-platform, parseui

I'm trying to import ParseUI as explained [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android) but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error:(5, 0) Cannot get property 'facebookSDK' on extra properties extension as it does not exist **Open File**
```

I include `compile project(':ParseLoginUI')` in my app build.gradle
as well as:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.0.jar')
```

any idea? TNX

Answer (score 1):

Re-read step 4 on the [the github page](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android). If you include the

```
compile project(':ParseLoginUI')
```

Try removing these. They are optional.

```
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
//compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.0.jar')
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the  dependencies  section of your app's build.gradle.

```
 // Module dependency on ParseUI libraries sources
 compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
 compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'

 // Uncomment if using Facebook or Twitter Login (optional Maven dependency)
 // compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
 // compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
 // compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.3'
```